# Android Trigger HTML Button Click in WebView From Code

Tags: android, webview, xamarin.android

My activity purpose is to allow users (employees) to transfer a piece of equipment from one location to another.  Rather than expecting the user to type in long serials/models or having to select from a massive list of existing equipment, I attempt to assist the user by displaying an ASP.Net page with a GridView contiaing all equipment in their current zipcode in a WebView.  However, if a piece of equipment doesn't exist in said list for them to simply check off, they need the ability to input the serial/model info.  I would add this ability to the aspx as well, except we may implement barcodes on the equipment and I need to be able to invoke the barcode scanning intent.  So I need to be able to do one of the following things:

1) Invoke the barcode intent from HTML button click in the WebView and return scanned value to somewhere that the aspx page can access for final processing

or

2) Since processing the checked rows in the GridView will be much easier using JQuery in the ASP project, I would like to place a hidden button on the page that does that.  Then place the visible Submit button in the Activity which will process any new equipment added there and also trigger a Click event for my hidden button in ASP.

Are either of these things possible?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningFromWebPages

Comment: Thanks.  I've tried that before and that method just takes me to a screen that basically just says the I don't have the barcode app installed even though I do.  Even if I follow the link to download the app from there and it takes me to the market, right next to the app it says Installed.  I submitted a ticket to ZXing and they told me it was a browser issue not having permission to invoke Intents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so just realized I don't need a button click in the WebView to execute JavaScript in my WebView.  I can just do

```
web.LoadUrl("javascript:processTransfer()");
```